# discord.py is only sending "objects" rather than actual information

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

Here is the problem:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YQPn.png]

Here's my code:

```
if message.content.startswith("%guildinfo"):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Guild Info: " + str(Guild.name), color=0xff00ae)
        embed.add_field(name="Owned Emojis: ", value=Guild.emojis)
        embed.add_field(name="Icon: ", value=Guild.icon)
        embed.add_field(name="ID: ", value=Guild.id)
        embed.add_field(name="Owner's ID: ", value=Guild.owner)
        embed.add_field(name="Max Members: ", value=Guild.max_members)
        embed.add_field(name="Banner: ", value=Guild.banner)
        embed.add_field(name="Description: ", value=Guild.description)
        embed.add_field(name="Splash: ", value=Guild.splash)
        embed.add_field(name="How many boosters? ", value=Guild.premium_subscription_count)
        embed.add_field(name="Channel List: ", value=Guild.channels)
        embed.add_field(name="Voice Channels: ", value=Guild.voice_channels)
        embed.add_field(name="Texr Channels: ", value=Guild.text_channels)
        embed.add_field(name="Max # of Emojis: ", value=Guild.emoji_limit)
        embed.add_field(name="Max Filesize: ", value=Guild.filesize_limit)
        embed.add_field(name="Members: ", value=Guild.members)
        embed.add_field(name="# of Members: ", value=Guild.member_count)
        embed.add_field(name="Created at: ", value=Guild.created_at)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Just so it's clear, what I want is it to send actual info not these objects.

Comment: My guess is that the Guild.<attribute> objects don't have a to string method which displays the value of the object. They themselves might have additional methods, or properties.

Comment: How are you getting the Guild object? Are you sure it is an instance of a specific guild or is it the Guild class?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to display information related to the guild the message belongs to. If so, you can use [`message.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.guild) to get this information. If not, please edit your question so your code is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For one, we do not know what `Guild` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Guild" is not an object, but rather a class.

```
class discord.Guild
```

Using str() on fields of Guild therefore doesn't return any values but rather information on the attributes of the class.
I suggest that you properly instantiate an object of the Class Guild using

```
my_guild = Bot.get_guild(id)   (pseudo-code)
```

You can find more information on this routine in [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_guild) and access information like this:

```
my_guild.name
```